# How to call the 'time_diff' filter in Twig

Tags: php, html, symfony, twig

How can I call the '**time_diff**' function In Twig

**The code**

```
{{ post.created_at|time_diff }}
```

**Output**

```
The filter "time_diff" does not exist
```

Comment: Did you register this extension ? $twig->addExtension(new Twig_Extensions_Extension_Date());

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you're using Symfony 2,

And want to use some of the [native twig extension](https://github.com/twigphp/Twig-extensions)

You have to declare as service something like :

```
services:
    twig.extension.date:
       class: Twig_Extensions_Extension_Date
       tags:
            - { name: twig.extension }
```

Comment: Works for me too. Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 3):

At first you need:

```
composer require twig/extensions
```

Then you need to register Date extension:

```
$twig->addExtension(new Twig_Extensions_Extension_Date());
```

After that you could use time_diff filter. [All in docs](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/extensions/date.html)

Comment: " Then you need to register Date extension " ; Where ?

Comment: Either as a service, or somewhere in Controllers, but first way is better.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest You to use the [KnpTimeBundle](https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpTimeBundle)

So you can simply compare with the current date:

```
{# Returns something like "3 minutes ago" #}
{{ time_diff(myEntity.getMyTimeField) }}
```

This compare with the another date:

```
{# Returns something like "3 minutes ago" #}
{{ time_diff(myEntity.getMyTimeField , to ) }}
```

The translation is enabled by default, simply review the translations files or add as you need.

Hope this help

Comment: I've set the locale as IT, but the translation isn't done. Any suggestion?

Comment: Using https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpTimeBundle seems to be the best solution for today (symfony 5). No customization needed just run:composer require knplabs/knp-time-bundle  and use it {{ date|ago }}

Comment: Thanks @marcin to confirm after five years that the solution is still valid :)

Answer (score 1):

Did you add the [date extension](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/extensions/date.html)?

Add the following line before using this formatting:

```
$twig->addExtension(new Twig_Extensions_Extension_Date());
```

Comment: " Add the following line before using this formatting: " , Where ;

Answer (score 0):

Just install the time bundle, and the |ago filter will automatically work.

```bash
composer req knplabs/knp-time-bundle
```

```
{{ post.created_at|ago }}
```

The more modern way is to use stimulus https://www.stimulus-components.com/docs/stimulus-timeago

Then the time shown is accurate, even for a static page (e.g. a SPA).