# Using Symfony3 and Twig, how to Calculate diff between two hours

Tags: php, symfony

i have many orders, each order has two fields for store the time of steps done.
the Variables set in Controller PHP

timeStartOrder = date('H:i:s')
....
timeEndOrder = date('H:i:s')

But how i render in twig the calculate diff between the time in twig?

{{ timeStartOrder=timeEndOrder|time_diff}} dont work!

Answer (score 4):

You said "don't work". But, do you any any error message ?

To calculate the difference between two dates, you have to create a function. In your case a **twig extension**.

- http://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/twig_extension.html
- [How can I create a symfony twig filter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11907137/how-can-i-create-a-symfony-twig-filter)

Of course, the function "time_diff" exist in the native support. See these topics:

- [How to call the 'time_diff' filter in Twig](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34001519/how-to-call-the-time-diff-filter-in-twig)
- [How to get days difference in twig](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30839618/how-to-get-days-difference-in-twig)

Install the correct libraries, and the twig extension to load this module.